# TypeError: Sporsmaal() takes no arguments

Tags: python-3.x, typeerror

Working on a program where the user get asked 5 questions, and then they need to answer which one is correct. However, I'm getting a TypeError when trying to run the code. The error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:oving_5/oppgave.py", line 42, in <module>
    questionList = createQ()

  File "oving_5/oppgave.py", line 28, in createQ
    question_1 = Sporsmaal("Hva er hovedstaden i Norge?", ["Bergen", "Oslo", "Stavanger"], "Oslo")
TypeError: Sporsmaal() takes no arguments

Process finished with exit code 1
```

What am I doing wrong here?

This is the code:

```
class Sporsmaal:
def __int__(self, question, alternatives, correctAns):
    self.question = question
    self.alternatives = alternatives
    self.correctAns = alternatives.index(correctAns)

def __str__(self):
    qString = "\nSpørsmål: \n" + self.question + "\n"
    i = 0
    for alternative in self.alternatives:
        qString += str(i) + ": " + str(alternative) + "\n"
        i += 1
    return qString

def qUser(self):
    print("\n Velg det ritikge alternativ (tallet)")
    uAns = input()
    if uAns == str(self.correctAns):
        print("Rett svar!")
        return True
    else:
        print("Feil svar!")
        return False

def createQ():
questionList = []
question_1 = Sporsmaal("Hva er hovedstaden i Norge?", ["Bergen", "Oslo", "Stavanger"], "Oslo")
question_2 = Sporsmaal("Hva er verdens høyste fjell?", ["K2", "Mount Everest", "Danmark"], "Mount Everest")
question_3 = Sporsmaal("Hvilken by er dette universitet i?", ["Stavanger", "Oslo", "Tromsø"], "Stavanger")
question_4 = Sporsmaal("Hva er 5 - 4?", [2, 4, 1], 1)
question_5 = Sporsmaal("Hvilken e-posttjeneste eies av Microsoft?", ["Gmail", "Yahoo mail", "Outlook"], "Outlook")

questionList.append(question_1)
questionList.append(question_2)
questionList.append(question_3)
questionList.append(question_4)
questionList.append(question_5)
return questionList


questionList = createQ()
point = 0

for sporsmaal in questionList:
    print(sporsmaal)
if sporsmaal.qUser():
    point += 1
print("\nDu fikk: " + str(point) + " rett svar")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote `__int__` instead of `__init__`. Therefore it isn't recognized as the constructor.

Comment: Wow, I do not know how I didn't spot that mistake. Thanks!